# Phone call function intent not working in android

Tags: android, android-intent, action

I have made a simple app,In that i want to make a phone call on click of a text view,But I am getting an exception that "No activity found that can do this action"..I have tried a lot and gives all permission to manifest,But still having the same error".

**main.java**

```
Intent dialer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                    Uri.parse("9033309332"));
            startActivity(dialer);
```

**manifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
```

Comment: Are you testing in emulator?

Comment: Your phone does not support phone. Try other device or test on emulator. And you are missing `tel:` before phone number.

Comment: I have tried on both the emulator and device...same error is occuring

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9033309332"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Most probably it may be because our device  grant the permission to that app then it may work. Just go to settings and grant the permission.